# Why is my text changing color when placed over a shape in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Both objects have 100% opacity. The text is definitely in front of the rectangle. What is happening here?

[image]

Comment: Overprint? Blending Modes? There **has** to be some aspect of the text object causing this. Check the Appearance Panel with the text object selected.

Comment: @Scott Oh good lord you are correct, it was on Multiply... Don't know how, must have accidentally done it with a keyboard shortcut. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Scott up there figured it out. The text layer was on blend mode of Multiply. Delete this if you want.